# SWIG : function that modifies its argument from c++ to python

Tags: python, c++, frame, swig

I'm new at SWIG and I work with a camera that uses SWIG to wrap c ++ in python. 
This camera is special because I can not directly get the raw images. I then find/add a C ++ function that would make snapshots, here it is :

```
int PixyInterpreter::get_frame(void){
    unsigned int size_frame = 8;          // size of the frame to grab print
    unsigned char current_frame[72000];   // ~largest possible given current hardware
    unsigned char *pixels;                //returned pointer to video frame buffer
    int32_t response, fourcc;
    int8_t renderflags;
    int return_value;
    uint16_t width, height;
    uint32_t  numPixels;


//  stop blob processing    
    return_value = pixy_command("stop", END_OUT_ARGS, &response, END_IN_ARGS);  
    printf("STOP returned %d response %d\n", return_value, response);

    response = 0;
    return_value = pixy_command("cam_getFrame",   // String id for remote procedure
                                 0x01, 0x21,      // mode 0 = 1280x800 25 fps
                                 0x02,   0,       // xoffset
                                 0x02,   0,       // yoffset
                                 0x02, 320,       // width
                                 0x02, 200,       // height (56 max @ 1280 w)
                                 0,               // separator
                                 &response,       // pointer to mem address for return value
                                 &fourcc,          //contrary to docs, the next 5 args are needed
                                 &renderflags,
                                 &width,
                                 &height,
                                 &numPixels,
                                 &pixels,         // pointer to mem address for returned frame
                             0);

    printf("getFrame returned %d response %d\n", return_value, response); 
    printf("returned w %d h %d npix %d\n",width,height,numPixels);  

// quit now if not successful:
    if(return_value != 0) return return_value;

// save this block
    memcpy(&current_frame, pixels,numPixels);

// display average and size_frame x size_frame pixel dump

    unsigned int i,j,ind,start;

// dump a few raw pixels

    start=(height/2)*width+width/2; //roughly in middle of frame
    for (i=0; i<size_frame; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<size_frame; j++) {
            ind = i*width + j + start;
            printf(" %02x",frame[ind]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

// run the last programm again
    return_value = pixy_command("run", END_OUT_ARGS, &response, END_IN_ARGS);
    printf("START returned %d response %d\n", return_value, response);
    return numPixels;
}
```

This code works fine in C++ and when wrapped in Python: it prints the pixel values.

But the problem is that I can not get the pixel values (array) **in Python** since the code c++ doesn't return it. Ok logic :).

My idea is then to use a**array of char** in Python which will contain the pixels value and could be modified by passing it as an argument in the function get_frame. The c++ function would look like :

```
int PixyInterpreter::get_frame(unsigned char *current_frame)
```

and the interface file **"pixy.i"** (partially):

```
%module pixy

%include "stdint.i"
%include "carrays.i"

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "pixy.h" 
%}
%array_class(unsigned char, charArray);

int get_frame(charArray * frame);
```

But unfortunately, in the python :

```
>> a = charArray(72000)
>> get_frame(a)
[...errors...]
```

it returns **** buffer overflow detected ***: python terminated* which seems to occurs at the **memcpy**!

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: python terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f63d95227e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x5c)[0x7f63d95c415c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x117160)[0x7f63d95c2160]
./_pixy.so(_ZN15PixyInterpreter9get_frameEPh+0x156)[0x7f63d801e636]
./_pixy.so(+0x10d37)[0x7f63d8015d37]
python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x5ca)[0x4bc3fa]
python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x306)[0x4b9ab6]
python[0x4eb30f]
python(PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags+0x190)[0x44a7a2]
python(PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags+0xba)[0x44a56d]
python[0x43092e]
python(Py_Main+0x612)[0x493ae2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f63d94cb830]
python(_start+0x29)[0x4933e9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-006de000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 9969410                            /usr/bin/python2.7
008dd000-008de000 r--p 002dd000 08:03 9969410                            /usr/bin/python2.7
008de000-00955000 rw-p 002de000 08:03 9969410                            /usr/bin/python2.7
00955000-00978000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
02404000-02548000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f63d0000000-7f63d0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f63d0021000-7f63d4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f63d6019000-7f63d601a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f63d601a000-7f63d681a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f63d681a000-7f63d681b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f63d681b000-7f63d701b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f63d701b000-7f63d7022000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2490667                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f63d7022000-7f63d7221000 ---p 00007000 08:03 2490667                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f63d7221000-7f63d7222000 r--p 00006000 08:03 2490667                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f63d7222000-7f63d7223000 rw-p 00007000 08:03 2490667                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f63d7223000-7f63d7239000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2494948                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f63d7239000-7f63d7438000 ---p 00016000 08:03 2494948                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f63d7438000-7f63d7439000 rw-p 00015000 08:03 2494948                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f63d7439000-7f63d75ab000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 9963184                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f63d75ab000-7f63d77ab000 ---p 00172000 08:03 9963184                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f63d77ab000-7f63d77b5000 r--p 00172000 08:03 9963184                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f63d77b5000-7f63d77b7000 rw-p 0017c000 08:03 9963184                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f63d77b7000-7f63d77bb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f63d77bb000-7f63d77d2000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2495090                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
7f63d77d2000-7f63d79d1000 ---p 00017000 08:03 2495090                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
7f63d79d1000-7f63d79d2000 r--p 00016000 08:03 2495090                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
7f63d79d2000-7f63d79d3000 rw-p 00017000 08:03 2495090                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
7f63d79d3000-7f63d79d9000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 9973881                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so.1.58.0
7f63d79d9000-7f63d7bd9000 ---p 00006000 08:03 9973881                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so.1.58.0
7f63d7bd9000-7f63d7bda000 r--p 00006000 08:03 9973881                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so.1.58.0
7f63d7bda000-7f63d7bdb000 rw-p 00007000 08:03 9973881                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so.1.58.0
7f63d7bdb000-7f63d7bde000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 9967987                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0
7f63d7bde000-7f63d7ddd000 ---p 00003000 08:03 9967987                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0
7f63d7ddd000-7f63d7dde000 r--p 00002000 08:03 9967987                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0
7f63d7dde000-7f63d7ddf000 rw-p 00003000 08:03 9967987                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0
7f63d7ddf000-7f63d7e03000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 9967992                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.58.0
7f63d7e03000-7f63d8002000 ---p 00024000 08:03 9967992                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.58.0
7f63d8002000-7f63d8004000 r--p 00023000 08:03 9967992                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.58.0
7f63d8004000-7f63d8005000 rw-p 00025000 08:03 9967992                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.58.0
7f63d8005000-7f63d802a000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 9699483                    /home/leat/pixy/build/pantilt_in_python/_pixy.so
7f63d802a000-7f63d822a000 ---p 00025000 08:03 9699483                    /home/leat/pixy/build/pantilt_in_python/_pixy.so
7f63d822a000-7f63d822b000 r--p 00025000 08:03 9699483                    /home/leat/pixy/build/pantilt_in_python/_pixy.so
7f63d822b000-7f63d822d000 rw-p 00026000 08:03 9699483                    /home/leat/pixy/build/pantilt_in_python/_pixy.so
7f63d822d000-7f63d8252000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2495082                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
7f63d8252000-7f63d8451000 ---p 00025000 08:03 2495082                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
7f63d8451000-7f63d8455000 r--p 00024000 08:03 2495082                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
7f63d8455000-7f63d8456000 rw-p 00028000 08:03 2495082                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
7f63d8456000-7f63d8493000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2495061                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.3
7f63d8493000-7f63d8693000 ---p 0003d000 08:03 2495061                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.3
7f63d8693000-7f63d8695000 r--p 0003d000 08:03 2495061                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.3
7f63d8695000-7f63d869b000 rw-p 0003f000 08:03 2495061                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.3
7f63d869b000-7f63d869c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f63d869c000-7f63d86a1000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 10096750                   /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f63d86a1000-7f63d88a1000 ---p 00005000 08:03 10096750                   /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f63d88a1000-7f63d88a2000 r--p 00005000 08:03 10096750                   /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f63d88a2000-7f63d88a4000 rw-p 00006000 08:03 10096750                   /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f63d88a4000-7f63d8b81000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9963224                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f63d8b81000-7f63d8c89000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2490396                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f63d8c89000-7f63d8e88000 ---p 00108000 08:03 2490396                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f63d8e88000-7f63d8e89000 r--p 00107000 08:03 2490396                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f63d8e89000-7f63d8e8a000 rw-p 00108000 08:03 2490396                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f63d8e8a000-7f63d8ea3000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2490612                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f63d8ea3000-7f63d90a2000 ---p 00019000 08:03 2490612                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f63d90a2000-7f63d90a3000 r--p 00018000 08:03 2490612                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f63d90a3000-7f63d90a4000 rw-p 00019000 08:03 2490612                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f63d90a4000-7f63d90a6000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2490656                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.23.so
7f63d90a6000-7f63d92a5000 ---p 00002000 08:03 2490656                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.23.so
7f63d92a5000-7f63d92a6000 r--p 00001000 08:03 2490656                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.23.so
7f63d92a6000-7f63d92a7000 rw-p 00002000 08:03 2490656                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.23.so
7f63d92a7000-7f63d92aa000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2490651                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f63d92aa000-7f63d94a9000 ---p 00003000 08:03 2490651                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f63d94a9000-7f63d94aa000 r--p 00002000 08:03 2490651                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f63d94aa000-7f63d94ab000 rw-p 00003000 08:03 2490651                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f63d94ab000-7f63d966b000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2490649                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f63d966b000-7f63d986b000 ---p 001c0000 08:03 2490649                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f63d986b000-7f63d986f000 r--p 001c0000 08:03 2490649                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f63d986f000-7f63d9871000 rw-p 001c4000 08:03 2490649                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f63d9871000-7f63d9875000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f63d9875000-7f63d988d000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2490648                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f63d988d000-7f63d9a8c000 ---p 00018000 08:03 2490648                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f63d9a8c000-7f63d9a8d000 r--p 00017000 08:03 2490648                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f63d9a8d000-7f63d9a8e000 rw-p 00018000 08:03 2490648                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f63d9a8e000-7f63d9a92000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f63d9a92000-7f63d9ab8000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2490647                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f63d9ae2000-7f63d9b00000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2490373                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.4
7f63d9b00000-7f63d9b01000 r--p 0001d000 08:03 2490373                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.4
7f63d9b01000-7f63d9b02000 rw-p 0001e000 08:03 2490373                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.4
7f63d9b39000-7f63d9c7f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f63d9c7f000-7f63d9c86000 r--s 00000000 08:03 10227159                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
7f63d9c86000-7f63d9cb7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f63d9cb7000-7f63d9cb8000 r--p 00025000 08:03 2490647                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f63d9cb8000-7f63d9cb9000 rw-p 00026000 08:03 2490647                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f63d9cb9000-7f63d9cba000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffd99927000-7ffd99948000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffd99985000-7ffd99988000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffd99988000-7ffd9998a000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Abandon (core dumped)
```

sorry for the long post, but if anyone would have any advice or explain how I could solve my problem, I would really appreciate it!

Plus, I've seen that *%Array_functions() and %array_class() should not be used with types of char or char* * :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to receive an array from C++ and have the changes you make on the Python level reflected in C++, I recommend you use NumPy SWIG bindings [`numpy.i`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/tools/swig/numpy.i).

Here I am using `ARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY1` such that changes you make in Python are immediately reflected in the underlying C++ memory (this means no resizing though).  Keep in mind that because the memory is owned by C++, you are responsible for cleaning it up.  If this does not suit your needs, you can choose a different typemap instead.  There is [good documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/swig.html).

**`test.i`**

```cpp
%module example
%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "test.hpp"
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
import_array();
%}

%apply (unsigned char** ARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY1, int* DIM1) {(unsigned char** current_frame, int* numPixels)};
%include "test.hpp"
```

**`test.hpp`**

```cpp
#pragma once

struct PixyInterpreter {
    unsigned char *frame;
    PixyInterpreter() : frame(NULL) {}
    ~PixyInterpreter() { delete[] frame; }
    void get_frame(unsigned char **current_frame, int *numPixels) {
        *numPixels = 12;
        frame = new unsigned char[*numPixels];
        frame[ 0] = 'H';
        frame[ 1] = 'e';
        frame[ 2] = 'l';
        frame[ 3] = 'l';
        frame[ 4] = 'o';
        frame[ 5] = ' ';
        frame[ 6] = 'W';
        frame[ 7] = 'o';
        frame[ 8] = 'r';
        frame[ 9] = 'l';
        frame[10] = 'd';
        frame[11] = '!';
        frame[12] = '\0';
        *current_frame = frame;
    }
};
```

**`test.py`**

```python
import example

interpreter = example.PixyInterpreter()
frame = interpreter.get_frame()
print(frame.tostring())
```

Example invocation:

```
$ swig -c++ -python -py3 test.i
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I /usr/include/python3.6/ -fPIC -shared test_wrap.cxx -o _example.so -lpython3.6m
$ python3 test.py
b'Hello World!'
```

Comment: Your example is pretty clear, and I tried to make it work in my code with some modifications, but it doesn't work. I detailled it in an answer post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your well detailled answer !

I tried your example and it works fine. After passing through some troubles trying to reproduce/adapt your idea to my code, now it compiles but doesn't work ... I made some changes in  the interface file, my complete interface file is :

**pixy.i**

```
%module pixy

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "pixy.h"
%}

%include "stdint.i"
%include "carrays.i"
%include "numpy.i"

%init%{
import_array();
%}

%apply (unsigned char** ARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY1, uint16_t* DIM1) {(unsigned char** current_frame, uint16_t* nbPixels)}
//%include "pixy.h" //<--- Error : Unable to find 'pixy.h'

%array_class(struct Block, BlockArray);

int  pixy_init();
void pixy_close();
void pixy_error(int error_code);
int  pixy_blocks_are_new();
int pixy_get_blocks(uint16_t max_blocks, BlockArray *blocks);
int  pixy_rcs_set_position(uint8_t channel, uint16_t position);

struct Block
{
  uint16_t type;
  uint16_t signature;
  uint16_t x;
  uint16_t y;
  uint16_t width;
  uint16_t height;
  int16_t  angle;
};


                       // Inspired from the block struct above
struct PixyFrame       // if not written
{                      // >>> interpreter = pixy.PixyFrame()
                       // >>> Error : PixyFrame not defined

   int get_frame (unsigned char** current_frame, uint16_t* nbPixels);
                       // if not added
                       // >>> interpreter = PixyFrame()
                       // >>> frame = interpreter.get_frame() 
                       // AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__getattr__'
};
```

I've seen many example like :

**foo.i**

```
%module foo
%{
  #include "foo.h"
%}
%include "foo.h"
```

but the last *include*  returns an error in my file: *Error : Unable to find 'pixy.h'*

I can almost reproduce your example with my interface file, but, when I call get_frame() :

```
>>> interpreter = PixyFrame()
>>> frame = interpreter.get_frame()
TypeError: get_frame() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

The 3 arguments needed are (self, unsigned char **, uint16_t )

and while building I get this warning :

```
pixy.i:17: Warning 453: Can't apply (unsigned char **ARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY1,uint16_t *DIM1). No typemaps are defined.
```

Comment: The only supported `DIM_TYPE` in the default typemaps is `int`.  To get a new typemap with `uint16_t` you will have to add `%numpy_typemaps(unsigned char, NPY_UBYTE, uint16_t)` after `%include "numpy.i"`.

Comment: As to why `%include "pixy.h"` is unable to find the file, I have no idea but that is probably just a problem of your include path.

Comment: This depends very much on how you manage your memory in C++.  As I mentioned in my answer (which is apparently not worth an upvote) you can also return a copy of the C++ memory to Python.  Then Python will run the destructor on its owned memory and you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Sorry but to be sure, how could I manage the destruction of the memory allocation made in c++? I define the destructor in c++ and if I'm right I should call it in Python then, but how ? I'm not sure if a simple "del" do it

Comment: Python is garbage collected.  When there are no more references to the object, the GC will run the destructor during its next run.  In your and my `test.py` this is the `interpreter` variable.  If you want to force collection, do `import gc; del interpreter; gc.collect()` but be careful: running the garbage collector manually usually trashes your performance.

Comment: Also keep in mind, that when you returned an `ARGOUTVIEW` and you run the destructor of the underlying C++ memory any access to the NumPy array `frame` will cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: You have 18 rep now, that should enable you to upvote.  You can see all the privileges here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: Sorry for the upvote (I had not enough reputations yet) but actually you help me a lot with my problem :D !

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, when you say "return a copy of the C++ memory to Python", it suggests that I could stop using the memory allocation ? Because I'm struggling with the memory management in C++ since my need of C++ is just to get that frame

Comment: I don't think it is possible without allocation, but you could certainly hide the allocation using `std::vector`.  However, you'd need a different hand-written typemap then to convert it to a NumPy array.